# Laravel Stevebauman location tracker not working dynamically

Tags: laravel, geolocation

I am using the following code to get User's IP info dynamically :

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
        $userIp = $request->ip();
        $locationData = \Location::get($userIp);
        
        return view('welcome',compact('locationData'));
}
```

And Code in my view page :

```
{{$locationData->countryName}}
```

But this returning the error :

> ErrorException
> Trying to get property 'countryName' of non-object (View: E:\laravel3\Currency\resources\views\welcome.blade.php)

It works nicely for static IP though . For following code it's returning "United States" :

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
        $userIp = '100.10.0.5';
        $locationData = \Location::get($userIp);
        
        return view('welcome',compact('locationData'));
}
```

Comment: Are you testing locally, possible to `$request->ip() === '127.0.0.1'`?

Comment: yes, I am testing locally .

Comment: So I assume package can't get any location from fake address (i.e. `127.0.0.1`). 
Try to test on remote/online server and I think you'll get satisfying result.

Comment: oh, thanks for the suggestion. I did not know "Stevebauman" does not work in localhost

Comment: You should stick with code form examples. [First example of usage](https://github.com/stevebauman/location#usage) has check which checks if object is not null.

Answer (score 2):

I use the code given below, which returns all the information dynamically:

```
use Stevebauman\Location\Facades\Location;
public function index(Request $request) {
    $locationData = Location::get('https://'.$request->ip()); // https or http according to your necessary.
        
    return view('welcome',compact('locationData'));
}
```

Comment: It does not return the right value when you include 'https://'.